# Python : Replace two for loops with the fastest way to sum the elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, python-itertools

I have list of 5 elements which could be 50000, now I want to sum all the combinations from the same list and create a dataframe from the results, so I am writing following code,

```
x =list(range(1,5))
t=[]
for i in x:
    for j in x:
        t.append((i,j,i+j))


df=pd.Dataframe(t)
```

The above code is generating the correct results but taking so long to execute when I have more elements in the list. Looking for the fastest way to do the same thing

Comment: If you replace 5 with 50_000 the amount of memory you'll need (ignoring the time that this would take) will be in excess of 100GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinations can be obtained through the `pandas.merge()` method without using explicit loops

```
x = np.arange(1, 5+1)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['x']).merge(pd.Series(x, name='y'), how='cross')
df['sum'] = df.x.add(df.y)
print(df)
```

```
    x  y  sum
0   1  1    2
1   1  2    3
2   1  3    4
3   1  4    5
4   1  5    6
5   2  1    3
6   2  2    4
...
```

**Option 2**: with `itertools.product()`

```
import itertools
num = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(range(1,num+1),range(1,num+1)))
df['sum'] = df[0].add(df[1])
print(df)
```

Comment: Did you try this with *x = np.arange(1, 50000+1)* which seems to be OP's requirement?

Answer (score -1):

**List Comprehension** can make it faster. So, you can use `t=[(i,j,i+j) for i in x for j in x]` instead of for loop, as the traditional **for loop is slower** than list comprehensions, and **nested loop is even slower**. Here's the updated code in replacement of nested loops.

```
x =list(range(1,5))
t=[(i,j,i+j) for i in x for j in x]

df=pd.Dataframe(t)
```